# What is the least expensive way to wait for a db update in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, asynchronous

I am working on an app where a value is input on page A. This input is placed in a database.

Then page A waits for something to be entered on page B and inserted into the same row.

Page A, while still in session, will need to then pull up the data entered on page B asynchronously.

My first thought was to have a loop that every few seconds requires the database. But that doesn't sound very safe or efficient.

Is there a better way for page A to get notified of this event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 
[long polling](http://blog.perplexedlabs.com/2009/05/04/php-jquery-ajax-javascript-long-polling/) and wait for something to happen, once it happens the page on the server will echo something and data will be sent on the client, then using javascript you can act accordingly.

Comment: Thank you kindly sir. I will test it out and let you know how it works out.

Comment: Hmmm it seems that I need to process the response in php... Any ideas how I can make that work?

Comment: I wish if you had explained what exactly you're trying to do, is it some sort of chat application?

Comment: I decided to use the jQ to pass the data I receive back to a proxy that will run the code. Thanks again!